# Generalized linear model for logistic regression in sap hana

Tags: hana

I am presently working on hana trial account. I am trying to perform a logistic regression with SAP HANA PAL (without using an R server). I would like to know whether glm works in hana without R studio. Suggest me if there is any possibility.

Comment: I think generalized linear model for logistic regression algorithm is not available in SAP HANA PAL upto SPS09, so you need R lang. algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the HANA Predictive Analysis Library (PAL) has a function for logistic regression. See the [PAL documentation](http://help.sap.com/hana/sap_hana_predictive_analysis_library_pal_en.pdf), chapter 3.2.8. You might also want to have a look at chapter 2 on how to check availability of the PAL on your system and install it if need be.